# Resolving eror from dsemg

Tags: networking, acpi

I just install Ubuntu as dual boot on my HP laptop and do not know much about ubuntu.
i get so many error that i don't recognize while executing
`dmesg | grep eth`

result :

```
[    0.280733] ACPI: Skipping parse of AML opcode: Method (0x0014)<br>
[    1.261757] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found<br>
[    1.261760] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found<br>
[    1.261761] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found<br>
[    1.261762] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found<br>
[    1.262744] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:05: WQBJ data block query control method not found<br>
[  213.888504] audit: type=1107 audit(1616676060.216:40): pid=717 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.13" pid=2438 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=720 peer_label="unconfined"<br>
[  214.530817] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [GINF]<br>
[  214.530818] Initialized Arguments for Method [GINF]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)<br>
[  214.530825] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GINF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.530829] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GADR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.530832] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.SGOV due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.530834] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.CGWR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.530837] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.TBFP due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.530840] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMTF.WMTF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536139] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [GINF]<br>
[  214.536140] Initialized Arguments for Method [GINF]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)<br>
[  214.536148] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GINF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536151] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GADR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536154] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.SGOV due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536157] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.CGWR due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536160] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.TBFP due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.536162] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMTF.WMTF due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20200528/psparse-529)<br>
[  214.683093] audit: type=1107 audit(1616676061.008:41): pid=717 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=2438 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=739 peer_label="unconfined"<br>
[  214.683360] audit: type=1107 audit(1616676061.008:42): pid=717 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=2438 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=739 peer_label="unconfined"<br>
[  216.854535] audit: type=1107 audit(1616676063.181:45): pid=717 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=2438 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=739 peer_label="unconfined"<br>
[  216.854938] audit: type=1107 audit(1616676063.181:46): pid=717 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=2438 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=739 peer_label="unconfined"<br>
```

What is the error about actually? How can I resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to update your UEFI/BIOS as that is what's giving the kernel wrong ACPI information.

If you can't update and your PC is running you have to ignore these messages, knowing that the kernel support for power management will not work (ACPI stands for   `Advanced Configuration & Power Interface`)

Comment: I did update my BIOS to the newest version but i still got the same error.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. What kind of hardware do you use? (Type & Model of your HP Laptop)?